# positive matrix of elements of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, positive-definite, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Suppose that $a,b\in M_+$, $x \in M$ and that $\begin{pmatrix}
a & x \\
x^* & b  \\
\end{pmatrix}$ is positive.
Is it true that there exists $y \in M$ with $\|y\| \leq 1$ such that
$$
x=a^{1/2}yb^{1/2} \  \ ?
$$

I know that it is true for matrix algebras (Bhatia, Positive definite matrices, page 13 or Xingzhi Zhan, Matrix inequalities, page 15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\e{\varepsilon}$

Fix $\e>0$
and let
$$
x_\e=(a+\e I)^{-1/2} x(b+\e I)^{-1/2}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}I& x_\e\\ x_\e^*& I \end{bmatrix} 
&=\begin{bmatrix} (a+\e I)^{-1/2}&\!\!\!\!0\\ 0&\!\!\!\!(b+\e I)^{-1/2} \end{bmatrix}
\!\!
\begin{bmatrix}  a+\e I&x\\ x^*&  b+\e I \end{bmatrix}
\!\!\begin{bmatrix} (a+\e I)^{-1/2}&0\\ \!\!\!\!0&\!\!\!\!(b+\e I)^{-1/2} \end{bmatrix}\\[0.3cm] 
&\geq0.
\end{align}
It is easy to check, from $\begin{bmatrix}I& x_\e\\ x_\e^*& I \end{bmatrix} \geq0$, that $\|x_\e\|\leq 1$. Using the ultraweak compactness of the unit ball in a von Neumann algebra, let $y$ be a cluster point of the net $\{x_\e\}$. Say $y=\lim_jx_{\e_j}$. Then
$$
x=\lim_j x=\lim_j (a+\e I)^{1/2}x_{\e_j}(b+\e I)^{1/2}=a^{1/2}yb^{1/2}.
$$